# MySQL SELECT not working for text containing a newline

Tags: mysql, select, encoding, special-characters, where-clause

I'm trying to search in a table if a text already exists, using PHP's PDO.

The problem is that if the text contains a newline character, MySQL does not find the row in the table.

My query is:

```
SELECT * FROM tableName WHERE colName = 'test
other chars \\ '' " _ \% àèìòù'
```

If I remove the new line, it find the row.

**Edit**:

I found that the `SELECT` finds the row *only if* the content of that row was saved replacing newline with `\n`, carriage return with `\r` and tab with `\t`.

For example, with `PHP`:

```
$text = str_replace(array("\n", "\r", "\t", "'", "\\"), array("\\n", "\\r", "\\t", "''", "\\\\"), $text;
$query = "INSERT INTO tableName SET colName = '$text'";
...
```

It's true to do that or I'm missing something other?

Comment: REGEX when used in your WHERE Clause will not destroy what is in the column! It only looks at the contents to apply the regex

Comment: @RiggsFolly I know that... I mean that I must escape much chars in the text searched in order to cannot be threated as characters for the regex (es. [], -, \) etc

Comment: This is not PHP related, most likely not even MySQL. Remove those tags.

Comment: @AmigoJack the PHP information is essential, because it can be the cause of the issue, e.g. encoding, php PDO, etc

Comment: Sounds like the text came from one OS and your program is running on another.  (Windows:  \r\n, Unix: \n, Max: \r).  \t is a different matter.

Comment: @RickJames correct, it may occurs.

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388305/is-this-an-appropriate-edit-placing-all-technical-term-in-code-tags/388308#388308

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that the `SELECT` finds the row *only if* the content of that row was saved replacing newline with `\n`, carriage return with `\r` and tab with `\t`.

For example, with `PHP`:

```
$text = str_replace(array("\n", "\r", "\t", "'", "\\"), array("\\n", "\\r", "\\t", "''", "\\\\"), $text;
$query = "INSERT INTO tableName SET colName = '$text'";
...
```

By doing that, It should works independently of which OS the MySQL runs on.

**Note**: this is only the explanation of why the SELECT could not find the row in the database, consider that every data entered in a query must first be sanitized to prevent errors or SQL Injections!

Comment: As I wrote before: that's SQL only, and in SQL you cannot have literals with a newline. But if you'd use PDO (as you wrote) and use parameter binding, you then would not have to care about issues like these. See my PHP code example. Your entire question started off why SQL could not deal with newlines in literals.

Comment: I can store a literal newline in MySQL by escaping the " \ " like this: `\\n`

Comment: `SELECT 'text enclosed in apostrophes is a literal'` versus `$php= 'text enclosed in apostrophes is a literal, but in PHP you can have newlines in literals';` - you still cannot distinguish both, hence your overall question(s).

Comment: I understand it. It's true, I used wrong the term `literal`

Answer (score -1):

Make an array of words you are searching. than place that array in SQL using `LIKE` keyword. your problem will be solved.

```
//Sudo for Understanding
SELECT * FROM tableName WHERE colName like concat('%test%', '%other%', '%chars%')
```

if you know any specific string than you can use it as

```
SELECT * FROM tableName WHERE colName like 'test%'
```

Comment: this isn't what I'm looking for. Please, read carefully my question.

Comment: you edited the question few seconds ago. Re-think what exactly you are looking for.

Comment: Even before I changed my question, your answer was not right.

Answer (score -1):

This sounds like you lack basic knowledge and/or you cannot distinguish the scopes.

```
SELECT col
  FROM tab
 WHERE col= 'with\nlinebreak';

SELECT col
  FROM tab
 WHERE REGEXP_LIKE( col, 'with.linebreak', 'in' )= 1;
```

Is your input the problem? Escape newlines. Is the table content the problem? Use `REGEXP_LIKE` to overcome newlines. Do you want to search a phrase that may have linebreaks in table contents that may not have the linebreaks? Convert your input into a regular expression. See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/regexp.html#function_regexp-like

Edit: an example from the PHP (PDO) side:

```
$sql= 'SELECT col FROM tab WHERE col= :input';
$sth= $dbh-> prepare( $sql, array( PDO:: ATTR_CURSOR=> PDO:: CURSOR_FWDONLY ) );

$sth-> execute( array( ':input'=> 'this
linebreak works' ) );  // But the linebreak is how you save this file

$sth-> execute( array( ':input'=> 'this\nlinebreak works' ) );  // Unbound to how you save this file
```

This still won't solve other problems like how linebreaks are saved in your database: it could be `\n` or `\r` or `\r\n`, and since you want an exact match you really only get that.

Comment: I asked for a solution for searching the **exact text**, so I can't use your solution: `.` match every character.

Comment: You don't understand: handing over your "exact" text is no problem, but what you present is SQL - in SQL you'd have to escape all newlines in literals. That's where scopes collide. If you use PHP's PDO then provide that code as example.

Comment: I tried replacing newline with `\n`, carriage return with `\r` and tab with `\t` in the input text (the value in the select) but it works only if I remove all the `\r\n`... what I'm making wrong? And what I must check to make it work?

Comment: No: using `\n` in MySQL and PHP has the same outcome, but the scope is important - to make that mask from PHP to SQL (so SQL interprets it) you'd have to do `$string= 'SELECT \'\\n\'';` and to make the mask in PHP (so SQL gets the linebreak character) you'd have to do `$string= 'SELECT \'\n\'';` - you don't have to do it on both, you "just" have to understand what happens where. Scopes.